# php to display table; column one with mysql column comments and column two transposed row results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, information-schema

Apologies for the perhaps poor title - It is best to display my goal visually:

I want something like this to show on the page when user goes to SomeURL.com/test.php?id=101

```
| Questions      | Answers       |
----------------------------------
| 1(a) First Name| Pedro         |
----------------------------------
| 1(b) Surname   | Millers       |
----------------------------------
| 2(a) Weight    | 150lbs        |
----------------------------------
```

This will be acheived by queries to a mysql database. Firstly:

```
SELECT * FROM Questionnaire WHERE idQuestionnaire=101;
```

Which returns:

```
| idQuestionnaire | FirstName    | Surname    | Weight    |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| 101             | Pedro        | Millers    | 150lbs    |
```

In my table settings I have Column comments set. i.e. For the Column "FirstName" the comments read "1(a) First Name". To retreive all of these comments I can do another query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAMES FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='Questionnaire';
```

Which returns:

```
| COLUMN_COMMENTS |
-------------------
| 1(a) First Name |
-------------------
| 1(b) Surname    |
-------------------
| 2(a) Weight     |
-------------------
```

The reason I want to automate the code with arrays/loops rather than hard code is because the actual table I am using has over 400 fields, and fields may be modified or added so I would like not to have to keep changing the php code as well when this happens. It seems like a pretty simple task but can't for the life of me find relevant documented solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the solution. Spencer7593 got me on my way but the final code required is as follows:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {echo "MySQL conn. err:".mysqli_connect_error();}

 $sql = "SELECT column_comment,column_name FROM information_schema.columns  
  WHERE table_name = 'mytablename';";
 $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysql_error());
 $columnArray = array();

 while(($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))){

 if($result['column_comment'])
  {
  $CurCol = $result['column_comment'];
  }
 else
  {
  $CurCol = "No text stored";
  } 

    $CurName = $result['column_name'];

    $columnArray[$CurName]=$CurCol;

 }

 //echo $columnArray['FirstName']; //test example to return "1(a) First Name"
```

So I looped through fetch_fields to get the corresponding column comments, and then looped through the result of the answers query to display each answer down the next table column.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use the mysqli `fetch_fields()` function on the result set, to get information about the columns contained in the resultset, rather than querying views in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

The `fetch_fields()` will work for queries that reference only a subset of columns in a table, or queries that return expressions, or return columns from more than one table.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.metadata.php

Comment: I can't make much sense out of the link. What on earth is select 1 as _One, etc? Also the output is not HTML table format. Appreciate the tip but this doesn't get me to the actual solution.

Comment: That link is to the PHP documentation. [http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php)  After your query returns a resultset, loop through the fields returned by fetch_fields (which gives you the name of each field, so you can output it, as well as retrieve the field value by name.

Comment: I missed that you actually wanted column comments, not `COLUMN_NAME` as indicated in your query of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Comment: OK. So I will have to use the information schema query. So If I get a resultset as shown in my question, with all the column comments, how does one loop through this to output as a table column, bearing in mind the adjacent column needs to be the results from the resultset of the first query (i.e. the "answers")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(SELECT 
 "1(a) First Name" as Questions,
 Firstname as Answers
FROM Questionnaire WHERE idQuestionnaire=101)
 union
(SELECT 
 "1(b) Surname" as Questions,
  Surname as Answers
FROM Questionnaire WHERE idQuestionnaire=101)
 union
(SELECT 
 "2(a) Weight" as Questions,
 Weight as Answers
FROM Questionnaire WHERE idQuestionnaire=101);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as stated in the question, I don't want to hard code like this as my actual table is 400+ fields and all the question text is already stored in the column_comments of the table.